# В unity как-нибудь можно повесить несколько спрайтов на один объект?

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть объект, который нужно раскрасить разными цветами. Пусть будет квадрат - верхнюю часть нужно сделать синей, нижнюю - красной. Я в графическом редакторе нарисовал две половинки квадрата таким образом, что при наложении друг на дуга они образовывают квадрат. Назвал их `sprite1` и `sprite2`.

```
SpriteRenderer sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();

sprite1 = Resources.Load ("sprite1", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
sprite2 = Resources.Load ("sprite2", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
```

И окрашиваю их так:

```
sr.color = new Color32 (199, 1, 0, 255);
```

Это значит, что спрайт, который принадлежит компоненту `SpriteRenderer`, окрашивается в этот цвет. А мне нужно разные спрайты окрашивать в разные цвета, но так, чтобы они принадлежали одному объекту. Пока мысль такая: создать столько дочерних объектов, сколько спрайтов, и так смогу красить каждый отдельно. Но смущает, что будут лишние объекты. Может, есть способ в коде сначала указать, какого цвета сделать спрайт, а потом объединить их в один, который можно будет использовать на одном объекте?
P.S заранее сделать 1 спрайт нужного цвета не получится, возможных вариантов раскраски очень много = нужно делать много спрайтов. Так что только программно

---

обновление:
При запуске генератор случайных чисел определяет, какой цвет будет у объекта. Дело в том, этот самый объект должен быть раскрашен разными цветами, но выбор цвета происходит только 1 раз (если это важно)

---

Обновление: Мой ответ не подходит. Дело в том, что у меня при выполнении некоторых условий у объекта отключается `BoxCollider`, а у `RigidBody` отключается `Kinematic` и `Gravity`. В этом случае у объектов на одной оси `Z` возможно наложение дочерних объектов друг на друга. Пример: `Коробка` и `Ящик` находятся на `Z = 0`. 2 дочерних объекта коробки и ящика находятся на `Z = -1` и `Z = -2` соответственно (по отношению к родительским объектам!), но у ящика дополнительно есть еще 1 дочерний объект на `Z = -3`. И вот, когда отключаются `BoxCollider` и `RigidBody` для одного из объектов (а то и для всех - не важно), дочерние объекты одного из них могут наложиться на другой объект (т.е на ящике будет виден дочерний объект коробки). Если у дочерних объектов будут координаты `Z = 0`, но при этом в `SpriteRenderer` изменять значение `Order in Layer`, то происходит то же самое.

Что делать?

Comment: таки может как-то через [SetPixels](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html) / [SetPixel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html) работать с одним спрайтом лишь?

Comment: посмотрел, что это такое, и не смог придумать, как применить к своему спрайту

Answer (score 1):

А я бы сделал еще проще. Сделал бы [спрайтшит](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cT8A0YwP9Y4)(анимацию из нескольких кадров с разными цветами) и просто переключал кадры по мере необходимости.

Comment: А эти спрайты будут на экране одновременно? Мне нужен просто объект, который я программно буду раскрашивать разными цветами - но эти цвета определяются при запуске, и потом до самого конца со со спрайтом никаких изменений не происходит

Comment: Sprite Sheet это система анимации для 2D. Все равно что добавить  на сцену мультфильм. Вам никто не мешает остановить мультик на требуемом кадре.

Comment: просто мне нужно одновременное присутствие двух или более кадров и чтобы они накладывались друг на друга. изображение нарезано по слоям, каждый слой я крашу определенным цветом, а потом объединяю все эти отдельные изображения в одно как бы целое - в итоге получается картинка. ну это  я так хочу сделать

Comment: Ну если вы будете на сцене использовать префаб с одним и тем же спрайт шитом, то думаю никаких проблем не будет)

Comment: либо я туплю, либо его можно использовать ТОЛЬКО для анимации(

Comment: Инструкция по тому как делать анимация из спрайтшитов в картинках (правда на английском) http://johnstejskal.com/wp/creating-2d-animations-from-sprite-sheets-in-unity3d/.  Выставить требуемый кадр: 
`Animator animator = GetComponent<Animation>(); 
 animator.speed = 0;
 animator.Play(“Animation_Name”, 0 ,(1/total_frames)*frame_number);`

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал все же не пытаться вот так в реалтайме создавать спрайт из двух других.
Во первых, на `GameObject` может иметь более одного экземпляра `SpriteRenderer`.
Поэтому можно добавить 2 `SpriteRenderer` на объект. Передать их в качестве ссылок скрипту.

```
public SpriteRenderer Sprite1;
public SpriteRenderer Sprite2;

//...В вашем методе
sprite1 = Resources.Load ("sprite1", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
sprite2 = Resources.Load ("sprite2", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
Sprite1.source = sprite1;
Sprite2.source = sprite2;
```

В данном случае, будет выполняться тот функционал, о котором вы написали.

Comment: При попытке добавить еще один SpriteRenderer показывает ошибку, мол, не могу добавить компонент, так как 1 рендерер уже присутствует. Ну и соответственно объединить два спрайта в одном не получилось. И `.source` он не знает - это то же самое, что `Sprite1.sprite = sprite1`?

Comment: @KremSoda окей. А как на счет того, чтобы просто добавить 2 дочерних объекта к данному? И у дочерних завести по спрайт рендеру?
Соответственно, в скрипт передать 2 этих дочерних объекта?

Comment: вот именно этого (создания дочерних объектов) я хочу избежать)

Comment: @KremSoda в ином случае, только если писать свой шейдер, принимающий два спрайта. ну или, как вы и собирались, по пикселям собирать изображение. из личного опыта скажу, что собирать .Net средствами пиксели в итоговое изображение - не самое оптимальное. либо на C/C++ найти что-то. использовать `Bitmap` с его `SetPixel` очень медленно работает.

Answer (score 0):

Пока что вот такое собрал (но опять же, хочу избежать создания кучи объектов, поэтому жду ответ):
На сцене создал пустой `GameObject`, на который повесил мой скрипт

```
public class TEST : MonoBehaviour {

    public Sprite[] bag;
    public Sprite box;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        CreateChildObjects ();

    }

    void CreateChildObjects()
    {
        int rnd = Random.Range (0, 2);

        if (rnd == 0) {
            GameObject go = new GameObject (); // создаю объект
            go.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer> (); // добавляю ему компонент SpriteRenderer
            go.transform.SetParent (gameObject.transform); // делаю новый объект дочерним
            go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = box; // говорю, какой спрайт использовать
            go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = new Color32 (215, 111, 14, 255); // говорю, какой цвет использовать
        } else {
            // ну тут аналогично, но добавляется for по количеству используемых спрайтов
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                GameObject go = new GameObject ();
                go.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
                go.transform.SetParent (gameObject.transform);
                go.transform.position = new Vector3 (gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y,
                    - 0.1f * i);
                go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = bag[i];
            }
            transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color32  (215, 111, 14, 255);
            // GetChild(1), а не (0), потому что для наглядности я заранее сделал моему объекту дочерний
            // - посмотреть, как они сортируются
            // то же для остальных спрайтов
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```